# Русское название барвинка

Tags: названия

Есть такой цветок - барвинок. Название его произошло от украинского слова "барва" - "краска". Я всегда считал, что слово "барвинок" - сугубо украинское (был даже такой детский журнал). А есть ли у этого цветка какое-то русское название или в русском он тоже называется барвинком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И "барва", и "барвинок" в украинском(как и тысячи других слов) - польские заимствования. А само название растения "барвинок" происходит не от  слова "barwy"- цвета(какие там у барвинка краски, все бледное), а от латинского per vinca(вьющийся), через заимствование из польского - barwinek.

Из Этимологического словаря Фасмера:
барвинок - нка, барвенок, -нка – растение "Vinca minor, барвинок меньший" (напр., у Гоголя), укр. барвiнок. Заимств. через польск. barwinek, чеш. barvinek, а также через немецкие формы, давшие совр. Barwinkel; из лат. pervinca; см. Маценауэр 18, Вернекер 1, 44 и сл., Корбут 428.

Answer (score 2):

Барвинок малый. 
Название растения у народов России: *барвинок, ворвинок, гроб, гробная трава, гроб-трава, гробы, зеленка, могильник, могильница, плющ-трава, увенок, фиалка ведьм.* Многие народные названия барвинка связаны с кладбищем, смертью. Это растение принято сажать на могилы умерших в знак вечной любви и памяти. На Западной Украине считалось, что барвинок появляется на могилах невинно убитых (http://www.plant.su/tags/mogilnica.html)

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, это  вьюнок?